# How to reference a View from within a Window Controller?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm having a Window Controller with a toolbar. I also have a View Controller containing some views. How do I reference a view from the View Controller within my Window Controller? I'm still learning macOS development and I'm missing the bigger picture how code is structured and classes are meant to interact.

My concrete problem right now is this: Using XCode 9.4.1 I have a window with a toolbar and a button in it. That's how my WindowsController.swift looks like:

```
import Cocoa

class WindowController: NSWindowController {
    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        window?.titleVisibility = .hidden
    }

    @IBAction func startExport(_ sender: NSButton) {
        print("Start Export")
    }
}
```

In the ViewControllerScene there's a WKWebView that's loading a web page. When the button in the toolbar is pressed, I want to call that Web Views takeSnapshot method. So I need a reference in WindowsController.swift to that Web View, but control-dragging the Web View from the storyboard to WindowsController.swift in the assistant editor doesn't let me create that outlet.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowcontroller/1532552-contentviewcontroller?changes=_4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
let vc = contentViewController as? ViewController
```

will take you to your view controller.

Comment: Oh, that was really easy. Thank you.